# XML Text Element Blank

Tags: java, xml

So very new to dealing with XML. I'm searching through an XML document to get a particular node and then printing the contents of that node. My problem is that I have several child nodes that are printing as blank despite trying to catch with the if statement.

Here is the code I have:

```
                for (int n = 0; n < childNodes.getLength(); n++) {
                    Node currentnode = childNodes.item(n);
                        result += node.getNodeValue();
                        String NodeName = currentnode.getNodeName();
                        String NodeText = currentnode.getTextContent();
                        System.out.println("Child Node Name: " +NodeName);
                        if (NodeText != null && !NodeText.isEmpty()){
                            System.out.println("Child Node Text: " +NodeText);
                        }
                }
```

results are:

Parent Node Name: section
Child Nodes: 11
Child Node Name: #text
Child Node Text:

Child Node Name: id
Child Node Name: #text
Child Node Text:

Child Node Name: code
Child Node Name: #text
Child Node Text:

Child Node Name: title
Child Node Text: INDICATIONS & USAGE
Child Node Name: #text
Child Node Text:

Child Node Name: text
Child Node Text:

```
                 Herpes Zoster Infections: Acyclovir tablets, USP are indicated for the acute treatment of herpes zoster (shingles).
                 Genital Herpes: Acyclovir tablets, USP are indicated for the treatment of initial episodes and the management of recurrent episodes of genital herpes.
                 Chickenpox: Acyclovir tablets, USP are indicated for the treatment of chickenpox (varicella).
```

Child Node Name: #text
Child Node Text:

Child Node Name: effectiveTime
Child Node Name: #text
Child Node Text:

I'm trying to isolate the paragraph of text in the middle and not the other blank nodes. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the XML you put as an input?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `NodeText.isEmpty()` with `NodeText.trim().isEmpty()` ?

Comment: SolutionMill - that did the trick! How do I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing NodeText.isEmpty() with NodeText.trim().isEmpty() did the trick!